# Is the custom Semaphore and it's usage even correct?

Tags: java, synchronization, semaphore

Is it not entirely possible that the ReceivingThread never gets a chance to execute and the SendingThread KEEEEEEPPPSSS....... on executing without leaving the lock on the Semaphore object at all? 
I got this example from [Jakob Jenkov concurrency tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/semaphores.html)

Can some one please elaborate and explain the example below about how the Semaphore is actually behaving like a Semaphore?

```
public class Semaphore {  
  private boolean signal = false;  

  public synchronized void take() {  
    this.signal = true;  
    this.notify();  
  }  

  public synchronized void release() throws InterruptedException{  
    while(!this.signal) wait();  
    this.signal = false;  
  }  

}  

public class SendingThread {  
  Semaphore semaphore = null;  

  public SendingThread(Semaphore semaphore){  
    this.semaphore = semaphore;  
  }  

  public void run(){  
    while(true){  
      //do something, then signal  
      this.semaphore.take();  

    }  
  }  
}  

public class RecevingThread {  
  Semaphore semaphore = null;  

  public ReceivingThread(Semaphore semaphore){  
    this.semaphore = semaphore;  
  }  

  public void run(){  
    while(true){  
      this.semaphore.release();  
      //receive signal, then do something...  
    }  
  }  
}  

class User{  
    public static void main(){  
        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore();  
        SendingThread sender = new SendingThread(semaphore);  
        ReceivingThread receiver = new ReceivingThread(semaphore);  
        receiver.start();  
        sender.start();  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, neither "sender" nor "receiver" seems to actually be threads.
(They do not extend "Thread".)

The semaphore in question does behave like a semaphore in the meaning that it is possible to wait for it to be released, it is not safe for concurrent signalling.

On the other hand you have taken code from a tutorial out of context.
Read the tutorial and assume it is trying to teach you something.
It looks like the next paragraphs addresses your concerns.

Comment: I am sure, just like you did, people looking to answer this question will "see" the "extends thread" where it is applicable and will forgive my genuine oversight. I see your point about reading further. I was hoping if someone could may be point me to the vital differences in the examples in the tutorial and "guide me" on how the Semaphore is "growing".